# Как загружать файл из поддомена в директорию основного домена?

Tags: php

Есть обычная форма загрузки на поддомене. Код ниже.
Как сделать так, чтобы файлы загружались в предыдущую папку, то есть /images/ а не /m/images/ ?

```
$final_width_of_image = 500;
$path_to_image_directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/full/";
$path_to_thumbs_directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']"/images/thumbs/";

$extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['avatar']['name'], '.'), 1));
if(trim($extension)){
$filename = substr(md5(microtime() . rand(0, 9999)), 0, 20) .'_avatar.'. $extension;
$source = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];    
    if(preg_match('/.+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)/is', $_FILES['avatar']['name'])){
       if($_FILES['avatar']['size'] != 0 AND $_FILES['avatar']['size']<=10000000){
        $target = $path_to_image_directory . $filename;
        if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target)){
          //Добавление в базу
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Попробуй во 2-й и 3-й строчке добавить к "/images/full/" /.. что бы получилось "/../images/full"

Answer (score 1):

Если есть доступ к bash и не хочется менять основной код, предположим у тебя несколько поддооменов которые работают с 1 базой картинок , то можно пробросить симлинк , находясь в папке /m/ выполни :

```
ln -s <target folder>
```

указав за место `<target folder>` путь до нужной папки . После этого все что будет лится в папку  будет попадать в `/m/images/` фактически будет в `/images/`

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Символьная_ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: А кодовый вариант возможен? Чтобы лишних действий не проделывать при установке сайта...Ну и по  вашему варианту, если загружать с основного домена, то они получается будут попадать в /m/images/?

Comment: Все будет попадать в 1 папку , это же просто ссылка. А в коде если то в первом ответе писали `/../images/`